# Can't get symbolicatecrash working, double Xcode installation?

Tags: ios, xcode, stack-trace, symbolicatecrash

I have found several posts on the matter and finally managed to locate the right symbolicatecrash on my computer. I did run:

```
  306      find /Applications/Xcode.app -name symbolicatecrash -type f
```

Which gave:

```
  307  cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/
```

**I have two versions of Xcode installed (the default one is the old 3.2 so I have every time to manually open the file and select to open with 4.3) so I am not that sure if the Xcode.app is the right path but there is only one folder called Xcode.app on my machine**.

When I run symbolicatecrash on the .DYSM file but here is the result:

```
./symbolicatecrash LOGFILE  /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCocos2dx-atifzmabifuzldejedlbjjibmljf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestCocos2dx.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist while reading LOGFILE, No such file or directory :  at ./symbolicatecrash line 645.
```

Any suggestion? Can this be due to having two Xcode installed? I can't believe that there is no easier way to analyze the stack trace and run symbolicatecrash.

Thanks!